# image position in div on screen html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I am building a dock-style menu. I have 4 thumbnails at the bottom and I want to pop-up a div. Everything is fine except one thing, when I am trying to position the pop-up div above the thumbnail, I cant figure out how to get the position of the image. I tried offset and $(element).width but both are returning the position of the bottom (main) div (which contains the thumbnail). What should I do?

Bottom Div

```
<div id=menu>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img id="fest" src="icon/fest.png" style="position: relative;"height="150"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img id="music" src="icon/music.png" style="position: relative;"height="150"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img id="diaf" src="icon/diaf.png" style="position: relative;"height="150"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img id="show" src="icon/show.png" style="position: relative;"height="150"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Pop-up div

```
<div id="diaf_div" style="display: none; background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5); border-radius: 25px; border: 2px;">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img id="diaf_1" src="icon/diafora/apokries.png" style=" height: 80px; width: 80px;" title="Αποκριάτικες Εκδηλώσεις"/>
    </a></br>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
        <img id="diaf_2" src="icon/diafora/docs.png" style=" height: 80px; width: 80px;" title="Aegean Docs"/>
    </a></br>
    <a href="http://www.hiddenlol.com">
        <img id="diaf_3" src="icon/diafora/grad.png" style=" height: 80px; width: 80px;" title="Ορκομωσίες"/>
    </a></br>
    <a href="http://www.hiddenlol.com">
        <img id="diaf_4" src="icon/diafora/valentine.png" style=" height: 80px; width: 80px;" title="Εκδήλωση Αγίου Βαλεντίνου"/>
    </a></br>
</div>
```

and the thumbnail javascript

```
//Menu      
var myElement = document.getElementById('diaf');
var position = getPosition(myElement);
$("#diaf").mouseover(function () {
    kathar();
    $("#diaf").css({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $("#diaf").animate({
        width: ($(window).width() * 0.06),
        height: ($(window).width() * 0.06),
        opacity: 1
    }, 50);
    $("#diaf_div").fadeIn(50);
});
$("#diaf").mouseout(function () {
    $("#diaf").css({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $("#diaf").animate({
        width: ($(window).width() * itx),
        height: ($(window).width() * itx),
        opacity: 1
    }, 50);
});

//Items

var
diaf_height = 400;
document.getElementById('diaf_div').style.height = diaf_height;
document.getElementById('diaf_div').style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById('diaf_div').style.left = position.x;

document.getElementById('diaf_div').style.top = $(window).height() - ($(window).width() * itx) - diaf_height;

$("#diaf_div").mouseleave(function () {
    kathar();
});
$("#diaf_1").mouseover(function () {
    $("#diaf_1").css({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $("#diaf_1").attr("src", "icon/diafora/apokries1.png")

});
$("#diaf_1").mouseout(function () {
    $("#diaf_1").css({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $("#diaf_1").attr("src", "icon/diafora/apokries.png")
});
$("image2").mouseover(function () {

});
```

Thank you and sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you

Comment: It is still not clear to me what it is exactly that you want to happen, and when you want it to happen (apparently there is animation involved now?).
Also: Are you using any other resources? Because: `ReferenceError: getPosition is not defined`.
The code provided mixes HTML and CSS and is therefore ideal, but more importantly has some errors or quirks (simply "</br>" instead of "<br />", ID for "menu" not escaped)

You might want to use the code as rewritten [here](https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/khgr5p1v/) from here on to make things easier for us

Comment: Furthermore, some function called `kathar()` is missing: what does that do? a variable called "itx" is not defined in this excerpt...
Please make sure you provide us with a working example that represents the current state of your project

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your layout:
If possible, create the pop-up as a child of the thumbnail. Set the thumbnail to

```
position:relative;
```

and the pop-up to

```
position:absolute;
bottom:100%;
```

See a dynamically created example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/ck25bgtn/

If you want the horizontal center of the pop-up to match the horizontal center of the thumbnail, this can also be done in CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/pt741nt7/

```
.popup{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The thumbnail is an img element which is a child of the bottom div, and I want the horizontal center of the pop-up to be the same as the horizontal center of the thumbnail

Comment: I see you still haven't provided us with any code: no HTML, no CSS, no JavaScript, not even a link. Without any help for US, we can't really help YOU much, beyond just guessing...
Where does the pop-up come from?
Please provide some code snippet to illustrate your problem.
Creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is the best way to do so.

Comment: I just want one thing, to get the horizontal position of an Img withing a div in pixels.

Comment: that depends on how the img got there in the first place. There are several ways to "ask for" the position, according to CSS, measurements in jQuery and browser interpretations. You know you can google those. A simple way to make sure you know where the img is would be to SET the position first (to 0px left for example) and work from there; and for stability's sake I would recommend using css `left:` for that.

BUT, I am afraid what you are trying to achieve might be MUCH easier if just done right from the beginning. If only you could tell us what exact BEHAVIOR you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I have a bottom menu with 4 images. Something like dock in MacOS. I want to pop up a vertical div, EXACTLY above the thumbnail. E.G. if I hover on the 3rd image, a div pop up with its horizontal center be the just above the horizontal center of the 3rd image.